# Why sass not compiling in Nuxt project

Tags: nuxt.js

I am trying to use Sass in my project based on Nuxt but no luck, I followed the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/pre-processors/) which tell to install few packages and it will complie. but I get the following error

```
error  in ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass&

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

body{
    ^
      Invalid CSS after "body{": expected "}", was "{"
```

and my code is in index.vue

```
<style lang="sass">
body{
  margin: 0;

  links{
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: try lang="scss"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some Info about Sass and Scss

> There are two syntaxes available for Sass. The first, known as SCSS
>   (Sassy CSS) and used throughout this reference, is an extension of the
>   syntax of CSS. This means that every valid CSS stylesheet is a valid
>   SCSS file with the same meaning. This syntax is enhanced with the Sass
>   features described below. Files using this syntax have the .scss
>   extension.
>
> The second and older syntax, known as the indented syntax (or
>   sometimes just “Sass”), provides a more concise way of writing CSS. It
>   uses indentation rather than brackets to indicate nesting of
>   selectors, and newlines rather than semicolons to separate properties.
>   Files using this syntax have the .sass extension.
>   http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#syntax

What you wrote is no valid Sass. If you change your `lang="scss"` then it will work and you still have the benefits of Scss.

TL;DR: `lang="scss"`

Comment: Thank you so much. I spend hours google and here i was using wrong lang type.

Comment: @Nofel ah happy to hear that it helped i had the same problem some weeks ago